# flex 3 charts export to pdf and msword

Tags: apache-flex

In Flex 3 application how to export the charts in pdf and word formats?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try [alivepdf](http://alivepdf.bytearray.org/) for PDFs :)
Don't know any API for word format. Hopefully someone else does.

Answer (score 2):

This library has JPEG/PNG encoding: http://code.google.com/p/as3corelib/

And since word is just XML these days (though complicated) you can export your view as images and then link to them in your word document. That is, if you want images. You weren't very clear about *what* you want to export, where you want to export to, etc...

And you'll need to send the data to the server so the user can download from there. There is no "local save" in Flash unless you're using AIR: http://www.adobe.com/cfusion/communityengine/index.cfm?event=showdetails&productId=2&postId=8406